# Error while running a simple GWTP Project in eclipse

Tags: gwtp

`I'm new to gwtp and trying to learn it .I am trying to run a simple gwtp project on eclipse (Kepler) and my gwtp project contains a new presenter I have created under client package and i have only edited the UI.xml file just to check .But I dont seem to understand what the problem is ,as I'm trying to run the project in super dev mode [Click here to see the console snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkLE0.png), i am getting this error :

Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] FAILED guiceFilter: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.Dispatch was bound.
  while locating com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.Dispatch
    for parameter 1 at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl.(DispatchServiceImpl.java:54)
  while locating com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl

2) No implementation for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.RequestProvider was bound.
  while locating com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.RequestProvider
    for parameter 2 at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl.(DispatchServiceImpl.java:54)
  while locating com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably missing the installation of the GWTP needed modules.

Client Module file you need to install the GWTP modules (`DefaultModule` and `RpcDispatchAsyncModule`).

You should have something like:

```java
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new DefaultModule());
        install(new RpcDispatchAsyncModule()); // binds DispatchAsync to RpcDispatchAsync

       install(new ApplicationModule()); //This is your main application module

        // DefaultPlaceManager Places
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(NameTokens.home);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(ErrorPlace.class).to(NameTokens.home);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(UnauthorizedPlace.class).to(NameTokens.home);
    }
}
```